# last two occurance of semicolon(;) in given String using Java

Tags: java, string

How do I get the after last two semicolon's occurrences of a string ?

Example:

Mobiles;Students;Test;Yes;1234

The output should be
Yes;1234

Comment: What have you tried so far? `String::split` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a regex replacement, we can try:

```java
String input = "Mobiles;Students;Test;Yes;1234";
String output = input.replaceAll("^.*;([^;]+;[^;]+)$", "$1");
System.out.println(output);  // Yes;1234
```